# Turn simple variable into an array (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift3

I had this variable in a my viewController `var category : QCategoryy?`
and I decided to turn it into an array so I created this: `var categories: [QCategoryy?]? = []`
but after that i get all errors like this

> "Value of type '[QCategoryy?]' has no member 'name'"

in this line `self.title = categories?.name`and other lines like that.

Why i get these errors and how can i solve it?

First to turn the var into an array all worked well. 
This is the class of QCategoryy

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name:String
    var isSelected = false
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension QCategoryy: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.name = value
    }
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have an _optional_ array with _optional_ items then getting the _optional_ __first__ item's name'd be like `self.title = categories?.first??.name`, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, you have converted that variable to array. So, first of all you have to give index of the array to invoke the value of object at specific index.
like given below

```
for index in 0..<10 {
    if let category = categories[index] {
         self.title = category.name   
     }
  }
```

conditional binding will prevent from crashing app if categories[0] is nil.

**UPDATE**

To prevent array index out of bound in loop. You can use below example.

```
for category in categories {
    title = category.name
}
```

Comment: in the conditional state, i have to add always [0]  as index of the array?

Comment: No, that's index of the array, check updated answer.

Comment: the app i crushing for this error "fatal error: Index out of range" , which may be the cause?

Comment: Your array index is overlapping the actual array size. Suppose you have only 3 objects in array, that will be 0,1 & 2. So when it'll try to search for categories[3] or above. It will give you this error.

Comment: because the max number of objects that my array can contain is 10 and minimum si 0 (i use a stepper to choose the number of objects)

Comment: You can get object count using array.count property or just maintain one variable which updates the stepper counts.

Answer (score 1):

Here **categories** is an array. So do something like this

```
 self.title = categories?[0]?.name
```

Comment: i have to add always [0] as index of the array?

Comment: Whichever index you want to access. It is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

categories in now an array. So you'll have to refer to some object of it whose name you name you're referring to.

More like, categories?[index]?.name

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use forEach:

```
categories?.forEach{ value in
    self.title = value?.name           
}
```